# conditions for a cyclic graph to be a subgraph of a complete bipartite graph

Tags: number-theory

Give the appropriate conditions for a cyclic graph to be a subgraph of a complete bipartite graph. Use the pigeonhole principle several times.

Answer (score 0):

I don't now where you want to employ the pigeon-hole principle, but $K_{n,m}$ clearly contains $C_{k}$ iff $k$ is even and $\le2\min\{n,m\}$.